# Delete lines above contentcontrol, run time 5941 error - the requested member of the collection does not exist

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a user form with check boxes, if the check box is not selected then I want the content control to be deleted and moved up.

I have content controls in my document like so:

```
Header 1
Body 1

Header 2 
Body 2

Header 3
Body 3
```

Each header and body are linked to 1 check box ie header 3 and body 3 should both be deleted and moved up if the checkbox is not ticked

I have this code but am getting an error saying the remeber does not exist but have checked that 100% does by using the same code to just select rather than delete.

```
    If cc.Tag = "DER2" Then
        If DERcb.Value = False Then
            With ActiveDocument.ContentControls(46)
                ActiveDocument.Range(.Range.Start - 1, .Range.End + 2).Select
                Selection.Delete
            End With
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: do you have 46 `ContentControls` in your document? always? in which line your error pops up?

Comment: yes, I do as it works for every content control up until this number and doesnt throw an error in until theere, is thera wwy to reference content controls by their tags rather than number?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess that this code is in a loop of some sort...

So what might be happening is that you are looking for the 46th ContentControl then deleting it.  Well... lets say there are 50 ContentControls in your document.

This is a `Collection` of ContentControls.  Now you delete the 46th ContentControl in your document --> now there are 49 ContentControls in the document.

You can delete ContentControl(46) 3 more times (it's a different one each time) and then you will only have 45 ContentControls.

Now, try to delete ContentControl(46)...   it doesn't exist, there's only 45 left.  VBA tells you this by throwing an error > `Requested Member of the Collection does not exist` (*meaning you asked for ContentControl(46) but it does not exist*).

If so there are two ways forward...

```
With ActiveDocument.ContentControls(ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Count)
```

OR

```
For i = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Count to 1 Step -1
...
    With ActiveDocument.ContentControls(i)
```

Comment: I am unsure what this is doing, I want it to delete the content control that it is curreently on if the specific checkbox value is false. BUt i want it to delete the line above and below the content control also so that it will "move it up" so ther are no blank spaces between the paragraphs

Comment: Tried this: If cc.Tag = "NS2" Then
        If NScb.Value = False Then
        With ActiveDocument.ContentControls(ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Count)
        ActiveDocument.Range(.Range.Start - 1, .Range.End + 2).Select
        Selection.Delete
        End With
        End If
        End If

Comment: Assuming that is where i was meant to put it and it doesnt work

Comment: Can you add a bit more code to your question so that it is easier to see what you are doing, will update the answer too.

Comment: Ah okay, sure what is it you want to see,

Comment: Heres an exaplantion of what im doing: Ihave a userform with many fields i then have a for statement that loops through the document, i have if statemts that fill in the fields with the text values, at the end i have some check boxes that i want to enter tesxt if the checkbox is true but delte and move up the blank spaces if it is not, any code you require let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
     If cc.Tag = "DI" Then
    If DIcb.Value = False Then
    With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("DI").Item(1)
    ActiveDocument.Range(.Range.Start - 2, .Range.End + 2).Select
    Selection.Delete
    End With
    End If
    End If
```

Solved above